# PHP Editor for Android?

Tags: php, android, editor

I have tried few on my android phone and they only highlight HTML/Javascript even though they offer shortcuts for php tags they don't have PHP highlighting. someone knows of one that highlights php?

P.S. dont get me wrong i am not going to program on phone, just in case i need to fix error or two on the go...

Comment: why not just use a SSH client and use VI or something simple?

Comment: Please explain what you talking about? how SSH has something to do with coding in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.touchqode.com/blog/010_php_ftp_support_in_new_version.htm#php

Comment: It does say it, indeed, but when i tried free version it did not highlight PHP code <?php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: PHP Highlighting for touchqode is advertised but not implemented.  Just tested...

Answer (score 6):

You can check out my app - [Android Web Developer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kidinov.awd). It contains a lot features, e.g.:

- Support all major web languages and formats: PHP, JavaScript, CSS, HTML
- A lot of ways to reach your project ( FTP, FTPS, SFTP, WEBDav and growing)
- Code highlighting
- Code completion
- Error checking
- Hardware keyboard support (e.g hotkeys)
- Code beautifying with one click
- Tablet ready UI
- Line numbering
- Quick preview of your page
- Highlighting the current line
- Search and replace with regular expressions
- Unlimited Undo/redo
- Full screen mode
- Recent projects
- Periodical autosaving
- Rename/create/delete/copy-paste files inside you project

I think it's most convenient for web developers than any that now exist in google play

[image]

Comment: Just downloaded it and started using it and it works great.

Answer (score -2):

Use a SSH Client if you're going to fix an error or two. You don't need some IDE with tag support for your mobile device if you're not coding, would take up to many resources IMHO

**connectbot**

- http://code.google.com/p/connectbot/
- http://jsharkey.org/downloads/ssh.html (Video)

Learn VI

- http://www.eng.hawaii.edu/Tutor/vi.html (I'm sure there are a ton of tutorials)

UPDATE (From your comment):

Use SSH to login to the server you wish to edit the PHP file on, I would suggest sftp. From there you can navigate to the file using commands like `cd /var/www/public_html/` and edit files like this `vi file.php`.

Comment: I'am kind of concerned about someone intercept my password when connecting to SSH from phone... on other hand if i use ftp client if they intercept and mess up ftp i still have backup of site and don't have to restore full server.  Besides editing file with 100 lines in SSH without any highlighting and everything word wrapped is kind of super annoying imho.

Comment: I suggested SFTP via SSH and if it's a quick bug fix VI should be great. Learning VI is another thing as it's very powerful but has a steep leaning curve. All the highlighting and stuff is great for a full IDE but not needed.